# Laptop freezes on boot, not sure where to start

Tags: boot

I have an Ubuntu laptop that stops responding when booting up. It will change between consoles with ctrl-alt-FN but pressing enter in the console would not even enter a blank line. The last printed line when booting up in recovery mode was "Skipping EDID probe due to cached edid". Any ideas what might be wrong?

Pressing ctrl-alt-del successfully rebooted it when in that mode. Another symptom is that GRUB stopped booting automatically, not sure if related (I doubt it).

Comment: Can you select rescue mode in GRUB's boot menu?  It has some options for trying to fix your X config.

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of graphics hardware you have -- Intel, ATI, NVidia, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an upgrade that wasn't finished. I started in rescue mode and run the command to finish the upgrade. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with ubuntu 10.10. 
Partial solution might be pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> when Bootsplash appears and then pressing enter. 
Works for me..

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic is bit different at the linked site.. but it can fix your issue too

http://zeeis.me/ubuntu-error-gave-up-waiting-for-root-device/ fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem might be with the window manager. Try getting into the shell without the GUI.

Comment: Can you explain, for the OP, how to do so?